# Protege-5.0.0-beta-23 is not showing OWLViz tab

Tags: graphviz, protege, protege4

I am using Protege-5.0.0-beta-23 on Windows machine. I have created an ontology. I would like to visualize my ontology with OWLViz. I have installed Graphviz and from Protege -> preferences I have setup Dot Application Path (C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.30\bin\dot.exe) properly. However still in Protege GUI, I do not see OWLViz tab. Please let me know how to fix it.

Comment: Any errors showing up in the console? Or, is there a red triangle in the upper left corner?

Comment: Does this require installing an OWLviz plugin?  Did you install that plugin?

Comment: It is not showing any error. May be it is plugin issue. I have checked "http://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/OWLViz". However non of the Plugins are available to download. Can anyone send me a working link?

Answer (score 8):

I am using protege5.0 on Ubuntu.But the setting is the same.You can modify tools menu item to show OWLViz. [Window]->[Tabs]->[OWLViz].
[reference picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAyV7.png)

Comment: Don't know why -1 - this could have been the problem and definitely it was in my case. +1 and thanks!

Comment: @Yong Qi This helped me in Protege Version 5.5 as well. +1

Answer (score 1):

Download instructions can be found in the link below but I've summarised the key steps to make it easier:

http://www.graphviz.org/download/

STEPS FOR MAC:

If you're on Mac, it's a pretty straightforward install - just open a terminal window and run one of these:

$ sudo port install graphviz

or

$ brew install graphviz

STEPS FOR WINDOWS:

Just head to the address below to download Graphviz and unzip and store the Graphviz folder within the Plugins folder in the Protege directory. Then make sure the Path to DOT application is referenced properly in Preferences > OWLViz tab > Path to DOT. Browse to where the dot.exe file is in the Graphviz folder that was unzipped to the Plugins folder

https://www2.graphviz.org/Packages/stable/windows/10/msbuild/Release/Win32/